# django project multiple user use the same project

Tags: python, django

I am new to django and web programming. Right now, I have created a django project for configuration form generation. It allows the user to input the values and generate a configuration form once the user got the URL.

[Project name: portal, App name: home, input_data.txt: a text file stored the values for the corresponding parameter and it will be read for further processing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oZf4.png)

It works fine for myself, but multiple users use it at the same time. It doesn't work. what can I do in order to allow multiple users use it at the same time?

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import FormGen
from .models import BB_Data

class FinalForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=FormGen
        field=['full_name','backbone_number']
class BBForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=BB_Data
        fields=['backbone_name','IP','numbers']
        widget={'numbers':forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly':'readonly'})}
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,HttpResponse,redirect
from .forms import FinalForm,BBForm
from django.core.files import File
import re

def replacePara(template,para):
    for key,val in para.items():
        template=template.replace(key,val)
    return template

def create(request):
    title="Router Generator"
    form=FinalForm(request.POST or None)
    context={
        "template_title":title,
        "form":form,
    }
    if(form.is_valid()):
    form_data={
        "HNAME":form.cleaned_data.get("Hostname"),
        "ROLE":form.cleaned_data.get("Router_Role"),
    }
    form.save()
    f=open('./input_para.txt','r')
    a=f.read();
    f.close();
    tt=replacePara(a,form_data)
    b=open('./input_data.txt','w')
    b.write(tt)
    b.close()
    return redirect('/backbone')

return render(request,"home/form.html",context)

def bb(request):
    title="Backbone Information"
    if request.method=="POST":
        form=BBForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            bb_form={
                'BBNAME':form.cleaned_data.get('backbone_name'),
                'BBIP':form.cleaned_data.get('IP'),
            }
        a=int(form.cleaned_data.get('numbers')
        datainput=''
        if a==1:
            f=open('./bb_set.txt','w')
            f.write(bb_form)
            f.close()
        else: 
            f=open('./bb_set.txt','a')
            outBB.write(bb_form)
            outBB.close()
        form.save()
        f=open('./input_data.txt','r')
        t=f.read()
        tt=int(t.split()[7])  #it get the max number of backbones
        if(at<tt):
            at=at+1;
            bb=BBForm(initial={'numbers':str(at)})
            context={
                "template_title":title,
                "form":bb
            }
            return render(request,"home/bb.html",context)
        else:
            # generate the configurate text file #
            content=final # content store the configurations
            filename="ConfigForm.txt"
            response=HttpResponse(content,content_type='text/plain')
            response['Content-Disposition']='attachment; filename={0}'.format(filename)
            return response
    else:
        return HttpResponse("something wrong")
else:
    form=BBForm(initial={'numbers':"1"})
    f=open('./input_data.txt','r')
    t=f.read()
    tt=int(t.split()[7])
    context={
        'template_title':title,
        'form':form,
        'max':tt
    }
    return render(request,"home/bb.html",context)
```

input_para: it is the text file stored the name of the parameter
input_data: it is the text file stored the values for correspond parameter
bb_set: it is the text file stored all the backbone information

Comment: What do you mean by 'It doesn't work'? Can you share with us some code and the error is giving to you?

Comment: @alessioferri20 "it doesn't work" means the data input from 2 users is interrupted. There is no any error message. The form generated is for router configuration. Therefore the user needs to specify the number of backbones. However, when User1 need 1 backbone and User2 need to configure 2 backbones, User2 only can configure 1 backbone. I think the data from user1 interrupt the data from user2

Comment: Do I need to use session or cookies to fix this issue? If yes, how can I use it

Comment: @Samon Ngai i can't help you without code to look for

Answer (score 1):

You're saving data to a single file, with no regards as to users.  If I go to your website, I'll be writing to the same `input_data.txt`, `input_para.txt`, and `bb_set.txt` files as anyone else also visiting.

This is *not* the way to persist user data for a website/service.  You should be using a database.

Luckily, you're using Django, which has phenomenal database integration, and it's actually really easy.  The hardest part, for you, will be designing the database.  You'll want a `User` model, against which you can record `input_data`, `input_para`, and `bb_set` data against, from what I can tell.

I recommend you follow the Django tutorial, specifically [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial02/#creating-models) section, and perhaps also read up on database design, (including normalisation of data, which is more interesting than it sounds).